# People Detection with CvSVM and HOG

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, libsvm

i'm working on a project (using opencv) where i need to accomplish the following:

Train a classifier so that it can detect people in an thermal image.

I decided to use opencv and classify with HOG and SVM.

So far, i have gotten to the point where i can

1. Load several images, positive and negative samples (about 1000)
2. extract the HOG Features for each image
3. Store the features with their label
4. Train the SVM
5. Get the SVM Settings (alpha and bias), set it as HOG Descriptor's SVM
6. Run testing

The Testing is horrible, even worse then the original one with

```
hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
```

I think i'm doing the HOG Features wrong, bc i compute them for the whole image, but i need them computed on the image part where the person is. So i guess, that i have to crop the images where the Person is, resize it to some window size, train the SVM on classifing those windows and THEN pass it to the HOG Descriptor.

When i test the images directly on the trained SVM, i have observed, that i get almost 100% false positives. I guess this caused by the problem i described earlier.

I'm open for any ideas.

Regards,

hh

Comment: "I think i'm doing the HOG Features wrong, bc i compute them for the whole image," - this sounds definitely wrong. i.e, the default PeopleDetector was trained on 48x96 pixel patches containing humans *only*

Comment: okay, i see. so i have to train von eg 64x128 patches of humans? and testing whole images?

Comment: yes. (not sure about the best size for this, but just remember, - detectMultiScale() does *upscaling*, so you can't detect anything smaller than your original Size)

Comment: This website might help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/